# Django drf simple-jwt authentication"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am implementing user authentication with django-rest_framework_simple-jwt with custom user, 
My models.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, alias=None):
        user = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username,)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
   def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
       self.create_user(email, username, password)
       user.is_staff()
       user.is_superuser = True
       user.save()
       return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username",]
```

So I am implementing restframework simple-jwt authentication,my settings .py is as follows as:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK={
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
      'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
   ]}
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^api/token/$', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),  name='token_obtain_pair'),
       url(r'^api/token/refresh/$', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),]
```

on login process, it returns error that `"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"` all my users were active. I have no clue to sort this out, I need help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30):

Ensure your password is being hashed before it is stored in your db. I ran into the same problem and discovered my passwords were being stored in plain text. Adding the following to my UserSerializer solved the issue

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def validate_password(self, value: str) -> str:
    """
    Hash value passed by user.

    :param value: password of a user
    :return: a hashed version of the password
    """
    return make_password(value)
```

Comment: Thanks I was useful for me. In my case password for hashed twiced since I hashed in validation, like you proposed, and then I used user.set_password which was also hashing it.

Comment: Great call! Just remember to first validate whether `value` has any value, because `make_password(None)` and `make_password('')` will also return hashes and it won't trigger the model's "required" validation since you're now sending some value.

Comment: How do I ensure that? Using postgres and data isn't stored in

Answer (score 4):

Either you did not create a superuser for your Django application or you are provided the wrong credentials for authentication

Comment: Thanks, my issue was because I didn't create any superuser account.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure, `is_active = True` for the user object that you are saving in your serializer, because

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['fullname', 'username', 'email', 'password']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        
        # Adding the below line made it work for me.
        instance.is_active = True
        if password is not None:
            # Set password does the hash, so you don't need to call make_password 
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Note ( As per docs )

The login_required decorator does NOT check the is_active flag on a user, but the default AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS reject inactive users.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set in settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.User'
```

Comment: I  already added. My app name is posts and I added it as ` 'posts.User'`, still it didnt worked

Comment: Did you try it in postman by passing email and password to the token obtain url? Your error says no active account found with the given credentials meaning you should check your database if users are accurately being stored as active.

Comment: Its not getting logged in, but if we use the super user credentials it gives the token.I am in the stage where I cant signin using normal user.@Leoog

Comment: If I could see more of your code and database I could help you fix it but like this we will just end up spending a lot of time and not get anywhere. Maybe you can msg me?

Comment: @Leoog I am facing the same issue. I am able to get auth token from  super user credentials but when I try with normal user I am getting  "No active account found with the given credentials".

Comment: @DarshanJain check to make sure normal users in the database are being stored as active. Django will not return auth token for inactive users.

Comment: @Leoog I found the solution, When I added password into the user serializer, It worked for me. I also added the validate_password function, just to make sure my password is hashed. 
Thank you

Comment: @Leoog your above comment about inactive users solved the issue in my case. I recommend posting it as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems my error was being caused by a `write_only` parameter on my password field

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
```

Removed it:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=68, min_length=6)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
```

and then it was all sunshine and rainbows after that :-)

Comment: Thist way you seem to be storing the password plain text on the database.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, username, password, alias=None):
    user = self.model(
    email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,)
    user.set_password(make_password(password))
    user.save()
    return user
def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
   self.create_user(email, username, password)
   user.is_staff()
   user.is_superuser = True
   user.save()
   return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded manually from PyJWT==2.0.0 to PyJWT==1.7.1 and solved our problem

```
pip install PyJWT==1.7.1
```

We are using djangorestframework==3.12.1 and djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0 on our requirements.txt and that gave us automatically the 2.0.0 version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is a problem where an email address and username is provided for the serializer, but an email is expected as a username for authentication.
I had the same error too. I also made some kind of custom user and tried to login to get a couple of json web tokens. But I only used email, not username. So what I did in the end and it works for me. Perhaps this example explains something in the place where authentication is done ...

Model and manager like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import (
    AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager
    )
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_or_create(self, email=None, **kwargs):
        allowed_kwargs = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'img', 'about']
        if email is not None:
            try:
                user_obj = super(CustomUserManager, self).get(email=email)
                if kwargs:
                    for k, v in kwargs.items():
                        setattr(user_obj, k, v)
                    user_obj.save()
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                email = self.normalize_email(email)
                user_obj = self.model(email=email)
                password = kwargs.pop('password', None)
                if password is not None:
                    user_obj.set_password(password)
                if kwargs:
                    for k, v in kwargs.items():
                        if k in allowed_kwargs:
                            setattr(user_obj, k, v)
                user_obj.save()
        else:
            return False
        return user_obj
        

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), null=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<CustomUser(id={self.id} - email={self.email})>'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
    
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'first_name') and hasattr(self, 'last_name'):
            return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
        return 'No fullname'

    @property
    def jwt_tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
```

Customizing token serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    def validate(self, email, password):
        try:
            self.user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            message = {'error': f'User with email={email} does not exist.'}
            return message
        check_auth = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if check_auth is None:
            message = {'error': 
                       'The user exists, but the password is incorrect.'}
            return message
        data = self.user.jwt_tokens
        update_last_login(None, self.user)
        return data
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('login/token/', views.LoginTokenView.as_view(), name='login-token')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Turns out that I had not included the password field among the fields in the Writer serializer.

Before I had code like this;

```
class UserWriterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_active',
            'telephone',
            'userType',
            'gender',
            'registration_date'
        ]
```

Then I added the password field to have this;

```
class UserWriterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_active',
            'telephone',
            'userType',
            'gender',
            'registration_date'
        ]
```

So in summary, some different value was being saved in the database which was not the password I added. Thus having that error, because the password you place as an input is not matching with what is in the database. Make sure that the serializer is correct