# User exists but not able to authenticate using simpleJWT and Django Admin

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

When trying to authenticate a user created through a view in DRF Browsable API, I get

> No active account found with the given credentials

[image: DRF Authentication failing]

The view:

```
class MyUserCreate(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The serializer:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=MyUser.objects.all())],
            min_length=5,
            max_length=20
            ),
    password = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            max_length=256
            )

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user = MyUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], password)
        return user
```

[The password is being hashed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56642683/5675325). At this stage, went on to the admin page and tested to login there too with the created account and got

[image: Django Admin problem]

Made sure the custom user model had is_active, is_superuser and is_staff and checked if that would fix the issue but it didn't.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(
            username=username
        )
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_active=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)    

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = MyUserManager()
    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'user_entity'

    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='userId')
    username = models.CharField(db_column='username', unique=True, max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(db_column='userPassword', max_length=256)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_id) + " (%s)" % str(self.username)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Then, tried to create the user using `python manage.py createsuperuser`... doing so then I'm able to both login in the admin pannel and authenticate that user with the Token Obtain Pair view shown initially.

[image: Django Admin login success]

[image: simpleJWT Token]

Comment: Once you created a superuser via terminal, did you check if the users are being created or not? As there must be entries of users.

Comment: Yes ofc. I can see them all in the DB @gutsytechster

Comment: I see, then the issue must be with the password. Can you check my answer below if it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. Thank you for providing all the details. It is always easier to debug. Coming to the issue, the problem is that you are using `make_password` explicitly.

If you would look through the Django's [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) documentation, you'd find that it takes care of hashing.

What you are doing is, first you are hashing your password, and providing it as a raw value to `set_password` method via `create_user`. The `set_password` would assume that as a raw value and would hash it again. Hence, your original password is not used at all.

You can just remove the use of `make_password` and instead change your serializer's `create` method to

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = MyUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data["password"])
        return user
```

This should resolve your query. I hope it helps! :)