# DRF simple-jwt error "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-custom-user

I can create an account with DRF_simple_jwt but when it comes to loging in to that account, it says
`{"detail":"No active account found with the given credentials"}`
I tried googling and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906891/django-drf-simple-jwt-authenticationdetail-no-active-account-found-with-the) and more but all in vain . I don't know where the problem lies.
here is my serializers.py code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class EmailTokenObtainSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    username_field = User.EMAIL_FIELD


class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(EmailTokenObtainSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data["refresh"] = str(refresh)
        data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)

        

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for user object
    """
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username','isAdmin', 'email','phone','room','hostel')
       

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    def validate_password(self, value: str) -> str:
        """
        Hash value passed by user.

        :   param value: password of a user
        :return: a hashed version of the password
        """
        return make_password(value)
```

and here is code for views.py file

```
class EmailTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

and here is urls.py:

```
path("login/", EmailTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path("refresh/", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
```

You can ask for further codes.
Thanks for helping because you are my last hope.

Answer (score 0):

in `CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer`you need to return the data

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super().validate(attrs)

    refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

    data["refresh"] = str(refresh)
    data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)
    return data
```

and not important but if you not adding custom claims to you token in your `get_token` method you dont need to override that method